# xunit InlineData tests are not found from CLI

Tags: xunit, azure-pipelines-build-task, vstest

I have found an issue with VSTS Test step where tests are rerun on failure.

If a test fails with "InLineData", I found that it's not found with the test case filter.

**Error Message**

> [xUnit.net 00:00:00.90] HGEM.Hub.UI.Tests: Exception filtering tests: Incorrect format for TestCaseFilter Missing Operator '|' or '&'. Specify the correct format and try again. Note that the incorrect format can lead to no test getting executed.
>   No test matches the given testcase filter `FullyQualifiedName=HGEM.Hub.UI.Tests.Features.GuestJourney.Tests.GuestJourney.BarometerScoreFilterArea(area: West)` in C:\Users\brian.mitchell.TMDC\source\repos\HGEM.Hub.UI.Tests\HGEM.Hub.UI.Tests\bin\Run\netcoreapp2.2\HGEM.Hub.UI.Tests.dll

**This does not work**

```
dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName=HGEM.Hub.UI.Tests.Features.GuestJourney.Tests.GuestJourney.BarometerScoreFilterArea(area: \"West\")"
```

**This does work**

```
dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName=HGEM.Hub.UI.Tests.Features.GuestJourney.Tests.GuestJourney.BarometerScoreFilterArea
```

But this will run ever variation of this test which looks like the following

```
    [Theory]
    [Trait("Category", "GuestJourney")]
    [InlineData("East")]
    [InlineData("North")]
    [InlineData("Northern Ireland")]
    [InlineData("Scotland")]
    [InlineData("South")]
    [InlineData("Wales")]
    [InlineData("West")]
    public void BarometerScoreFilterArea(string area)
    {
        this.Given(_ => _navigationSteps.WhenIClickOn("GuestJourney"))
            .When(_=>_common.WhenIFilterDatesBy("Current Period"))
            .And(_=>_common.WhenIFilterAreaBy(area))
            .Then(_=>_common.ThenISeeABarometerScore())
            .BDDfy<GuestJourneyStory>("Barometer Score filter area");
    }
```

So my question is this a bug in VSTS?
Am i missing some configuration to deal with the rerun of "Theory" Tests?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an open issue of dotnet test currently. A similar issue was reported and tracked [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/13963)